# What type of datastructure is this: a:114:{s:12:"notification";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:8:"email_to";s:24

Tags: database, wordpress, data-structures, formatting, marshalling

I'm working with a Wordpress database and want to create some reports on the data. One of the tables contain information which is stored in this format:

```
a:201:{s:16:"arfmainformwidth";s:3:"550";s:15:"form_width_unit";s:2:"px";s:8:"edit_msg";s:39:"Your submission was successfully saved.";s:12:"update_value";s:6:"Update";s:12:"arfeditoroff";b:0;s:19:" ....}
```

What I figuered out is that the first letter is the datatype: a = array, s = string ... and the second value is the length.

I saw this format in different other tables from other plugin and want to know how is it called or if there's any type of function which can parse this data. I don't even know how it's called.

I'm working with Wordpress and ARForms. Caldera Forms include this data aswell.

your help would be appreciated

Comment: Read these documentations: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_serialize/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the serialized representation of an array. You should be able to unserialize it by calling unserialize() on the string above. This is mostly used when you want to persist a temporary state of an object or you don't want to create database table structures for each and every bit of information.
More to find here:

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.serialize.php
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.unserialize.php